# Swift func signature and default parameter values syntax?

Tags: swift, function, closures

Can a Swift func/closure signature specify that default parameter values are provided?

A highly simplified version of what I'm trying to do is this:

```
struct L {
    typealias W = ((String, String, String) -> Void)
    static func w(_ w:String, _ t:String = "t", _ f:String = "f") {
        let line = w + t + f
        print(line)
    }
    static let ws:[W] = [L.w, L.w]
}

L.ws[0]("sue", "seven", "red")
L.ws[0]("bill")
```

The error I get at the "bill" call is: `error: missing argument for parameter #2 in call`

I tried changing the typealias line to:

`typealias W = ((String, String = "t", String = "f") -> Void)`

But that gives me an error at the typealias line: `error: default argument not permitted in a tuple type`

This does not help either:

`typealias W = ((String, String?, String?) -> Void)`

Comment: Swift does not automatically generate thunks for decorating functions with their default arguments. Even though your func `w` has defaulted arguments, its type is still `(String, String, String) -> Void`

Comment: What exactly are you trying achieve?

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for helping with valuable input, but I prefer not to enter into an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+problem) discussion on this question/answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following radar:

- https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/12160
- http://www.openradar.me/18041799

Was marked as fixed in the following validation test:

- [swift/validation-test/compiler_crashers_fixed/00023-getcallerdefaultarg.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/b9363fe6bd6c4b595d9c9ce11f91e715b3f6d3b7/validation-test/compiler_crashers_fixed/00023-getcallerdefaultarg.swift)

> ```
> // Test case submitted to project by https://github.com/practicalswift (practicalswift)
> // http://www.openradar.me/18041799
> // https://gist.github.com/stigi/336a9851cd80fdef22ed
> func a(b: Int = 0) {
> }
> let c = a
> c() // expected-error {{missing argument for parameter #1 in call}}
> ```

Based on the validation test above (particularly the expected error), I believe calling a function via a stored reference to it (e.g. `L.ws[0]` in your example) will not allow omitting arguments even if the function pointed to supplies default parameter values for these omitted arguments.

The type of the `c` stored closure (/function reference) above will be inferred to as `(Int) -> ()`, and will contain no information regarding default parameter values. When attempting to call `c` as if it were a closure/function pointer of type `() - > ()`, the missing argument error will be prompted without any possibility of tapping into the compiler magic that works when directly calling a function (not via a stored reference/closure to it!) that, in itself, allows omitting arguments for parameters with default values.

Comment: Seems to me like the only real solution to this is to introduce `defaultness`  into the type-system, so that `a` can have a type `(defaulted Int) -> ()`, which would allow for both `c()` and `c(0)`, down the line. I don't think that complexity is worthwhile for this particular use case. However, I think it would be a cool way of solving another issue: you could introduce a syntax for querying a function's default value, with something like `c.0.defaultValue`

Comment: @Alexander agreed. Such a query feature would be neat indeed!